# UIImageView missing when the app is running in a device

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, device

I am adding a UIImageView to my view in viewDidLoad.

It works fine when I run the application using the simulator, but when I use a device the image is not shown.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the code sample?  Where are you loading the image file from?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the image, not the ImageView, is missing. How are you loading the Image into the ImageView? Make sure that you are loading an image that is part of your XCode project so that it gets released along with the app itself.

Comment: Also double check the image name.  Simulator is not caps-sensitive, but the device is.

Comment: UIImageView *backImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

Comment: Is background.png added to your XCode project?

Comment: the image name is lowercase as I am setting in imageNamed

Comment: Yes, make sure that `background.png` is within `Copy Bundle Resources` of your target.

Comment: Let's try to set the backgroundColor to [UIColor blueColor] and see if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy question. Is it included as part of your build target?